# Can YouTube be started in pause mode?

Tags: youtube

Is there a URL parameter for youtube.com that makes it possible to open a video and *not* have it start playing automatically?

There is a parameter for the embedded player (`autoplay=0`), but this does not seem to work with the full site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [TubeStop extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6648/) for Firefox prevents autoplaying YouTube movies whenever they appear (within Firefox).

The extension developer also [provides a version for Chrome](http://www.chrisfinke.com/2009/03/18/tubestop-for-google-chrome/), which I haven't checked.

Comment: chrome extension does not work for me

Comment: Hm, yeah. But nothing that would work everywhere. Too bad. Anyway, that's an answer, too.

Comment: For Chrome, I used to use the [Stop Autoplay for Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgdfnbpkmkkdhgidgcpdkgpdlfjcgnnh?hl=en-US&hc=search&hcp=main) extension.  Haven't used it in a little while, but it always worked fine for me.

Comment: TubeStop was discontinued on December 25, 2012 and is no longer supported, for both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

try [smartvideo for youtube](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/?src=search). once installed, in the configuration settings you'd have to tick the box 'start playing when buffered' first before you can check "don't play; only notify when video has buffered."

works for embedded videos as well.